# gethostbyaddr and netdb implementation file

Tags: c, networking, dns, gethostbyaddr

Where is gethostbyaddr and netdb.h functions implemented? I can only find the header file where it is extern'ed (netdb.h)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implemented in glibc.

BTW, use getnameinfo() and getaddrinfo().  gethostbyaddr() is obsolete, mostly because of IPv6.

Comment: More correctly, it's implemented in **libc**. Which happens to be  **glibc** in almost all non-embedded Linux systems (and in Hurd, I guess)

Comment: @Celada True.  It is also notable that ucLibc does not implement these functions the same way as the other libc packages.